# How to remove columns with duplicate values in all rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I would like to remove from my dataframe columns with duplicate values in all rows.

I've got dataframe like this:

```
test =     [('a', 1, 'a', 34, 'b', 34,'a'),
                ('a', 1, 'a', 30, 'v', 30,'a'),
                ('a', 1, 'a', 16, 'a', 16,'a'),
                ('a', 1, 'a', 30, 'a', 30,'a'),
                ('a', 1, 'a', 30, 'v', 30,'a'),
                ('a', 1, 'a', 30, 'd', 30,'a'),
                ('a', 1, 'a', 40, 'a', 40,'a'),
                ('a', 1, 'a', 30, 'a', 30,'a')
                ]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7'])
```

As you see columns: col1, col3, col4, col6, col7 have duplicate values in all rows and my excepted output should be dataframe without duplicate columns. To be more precise, I would like to keep only one of duplicate column, could be e.g. col1 and col4

Comment: I saw drop_duplicates but it works for rows and there's no axis argument. Is there maybe counterpart this function for columns?

Answer (score 2):

First transpose, then remove duplicates per all rows and last transpose back:

```
test_df = test_df.T.drop_duplicates().T
print (test_df)
  col1 col2 col4 col5
0    a    1   34    b
1    a    1   30    v
2    a    1   16    a
3    a    1   30    a
4    a    1   30    v
5    a    1   30    d
6    a    1   40    a
7    a    1   30    a
```

Another solution is convert column to tuples, call [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with inverse mask with `~` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
test_df = test_df.loc[:, ~test_df.apply(tuple).duplicated()]
```